# VBA : Unable to get the Match property of WorkSheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of Names in the sheet "ClaimAnalysis", and a subset of these Name Values in the sheet "Analysis". To select the Names that have values in "Analysis1", I used Index-Match function for each value in the column of "ClaimAnalysis" (frow is the count of total rows in "ClaimAnalysis"). The formula I am applying works fine manually Formula Bar but throws 'runtime error in VBA.

Formula Bar "=INDEX(Analysis1!$B$2:$B$717,MATCH(ClaimAnalysis!A2,Analysis2!$A$2:$A$727,0))"

and yes variable frow makes my range as per desired in formula bar

```
For x = 2 To frow - 1        
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ClaimAnalysis").Cells(x, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Analysis1").Range("B2").End(xlDown), Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ClaimAnalysis").Cells(x, 1), Sheets("Analysis1").Range("A2").End(xlDown), 0))
Next x
```

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like you are providing incorrect arguments to `MATCH`. You are supplying a single cell address where it expects an array. This might be a source of error.

Inside the `MATCH` function, change this:

`Sheets("Analysis1").Range("A2").End(xlDown)`
to this:
`Sheets("Analysis1").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlUp))`

Another possibility is that `MATCH` doesn't actually find anything, meaning it returns an error.

Additionally, using `End(xlDown)` gives you the lower-most cell, not the last-most cell. If you are looking for the latter, `End(xlUp)` would be a better choice.

Maybe you can try this code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim matched As Variant
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ClaimAnalysis")

For x = 2 To frow - 1
    matched = Application.Match(ws.Cells(x, 1), ws.Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlUp)), 0)
    If Not IsError(matched) Then ws.Cells(x, 2).Value = Application.Index(ws.Range("B2").End(xlUp), matched, 0)
Next x
```